# My express.js is not receiving the body that I sent from react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express

I have a api object set up like this in react native:

```
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage"; //npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "localhost url here",
});
/**
 * This will add a header if we have a token only,
 * we will be adding a Authorization header to our instance before running
 * the http req
 */
instance.interceptors.request.use(
  //this will be called before doing the http request,
  //it is async because to retrieve the storage it is async
  async (config) => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token"); //awaits until it gets token (IF THERE IS ONE)
    //if there is a token
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`; //add string 'Bearer withGivenTOKEN'
    }
    return config;
  },
  (err) => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);

export default instance;
```

When doing the api call I am doing this:

```
await myApi
    .get("/routeHere", {
      latitude: currentLocation.latitude,
      longitude: currentLocation.longitude,
    })
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

When receiving the data the body part is just a an empty object. Is there a reason why this happens? Am I doing something wrong?

```
router.get("/routeHere", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("here is my body: ", req.body);
}
```

I think I'm missing to add the header type, but not sure if it will work, and if it is, how can you write it? I'm new to express and react native

Comment: Where do you send a post request to 'routeHere' from? Because req.body is available in the post request

Comment: I sent it at the beginning of the app creation. Using a useEffect(() => , []), I tried using a post and it did work. I can't send a body using a GET request with axios? Because in POSTMAN I was able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET request shouldn't include data.

> The HTTP GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only be used to request data (they shouldn't include data).

[GET method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)

But you can use params to send the latitude and the longitude, like this:

```
await myApi
    .get(`/routeHere?latitude=${currentLocation.latitude}&longitude=${currentLocation.longitude}`)
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

or

```
 await myApi
 .get("/routeHere", {
    params: {
      latitude: currentLocation.latitude,
      longitude: currentLocation.longitude,
    }
 })
.then((response) => console.log(response))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

And you can receive it in the backend with `req.query.latitude` and `req.query.longitude`

Comment: _"You can't send data in a GET request."_ That's wrong. You can. [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/) is an example for a widely used tool that supports GET requests with body.

Comment: The HTTP spec says "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.". Browsers won't let you send a body in a GET request. I don't know if the APIs used by React Native share that very sensible limitation.

Comment: There no way to send a body using Axios GET? I was able to do it in Postman

Comment: @Jerry310 —  In browsers `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` do not.. In browsers Axios is a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`. Postman is not a browser and allows you to do lots of things that browsers forbid.